# Use javascript to set value of input tag

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run a script inside a form which calculates a discount based on the quantity a user selects. The form is submitted to a payment gateway, and must include this tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="discount" value="0.00"/>
```

Where the discount value changes according to the user's selection.

So this is how my form looks, but the tag isn't being sent properly. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
<select name="quantity">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
<input type="hidden" name="discount"
if (quantity==3)
   {
   value="5.00";
   }
 else if (quantity==2)
   {
   value="2.00";
   }
 else
   {
   value="0.00";
   }
/> 
</script>
```

I'm so noob - but I have been trying my best! Please help...

Comment: Instead of guessing, please just take a book and start with *basics*. This is syntactically just plain non-sense.

Comment: I don't program in JS and was just attempting a workaround to a previous question that was 'not possible to answer'. It's really quite insulting to read your comment when you have no idea of the research that I've already undertaken to try and fix what I thought was a basic problem. Maybe should read a book about basic courtesy to newcomers.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you need to know basics of a language before you can do anything with it. Also you should stick with your question and not start opening new threads after every comment. I don't know what research you have done, but it certainly didn't incude the first chapter of any Javascript book.

Comment: @user2976186: you cannot combine HTML and JavaScript in a script block, like you do here: `<input type="hidden" name="discount"
if (quantity==3)`. Instead you should have the HTML separate and then listen for (e..g `change`) events in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two main problems:

1. You combine HTML and JavaScript into a single block
2. You fail to ensure that your JavaScript executes when the user changes the quantity

Your first step should be to separate the `<input type="hidden" name="discount" />` out from the JavaScript block. It is HTML not JavaScript, so the JavaScript engine won't know what to do with it.

```
<input type="hidden" name="discount" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
if (quantity==3)
{
   value="5.00";
}
else if (quantity==2)
{
   value="2.00";
}
else
{
   value="0.00";
}
</script>
```

Next up you need to ensure the JavaScript gets executed when the user changes the quantity. To do this, put your code into a named function and wire that up to the `onchange` event if the `quantity` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateDiscount()
{
    var select = document.getElementById("quantity");
    var quantity = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    if (quantity==3)
    {
       value="5.00";
    }
    else if (quantity==2)
    {
       value="2.00";
    }
    else
    {
       value="0.00";
    }
}
document.getElementById("quantity").onchange = updateDiscount;
</script>
```

Note that we now also look up the quantity value in the JavaScript. This is again because you cannot simply mix JavaScript and HTML in the way you did. For the lookup to work, you will need to add `id` attributes to your elements with the same value as your current `name` attributes (which are needed when you submit the form).

With these changes you are almost there. You're now setting the discount into a variable `value`, while you want it to go into the `discount` field of your form. To get this, you'll need to look up that element and set its value, like this:

```
document.getElementById("discount").value = value;
```

**Complete HTML**

```
<select name="quantity" id="quantity">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="discount" id="discount" />
```

**Complete JavaScript**

```
function updateDiscount()
{
    var select = document.getElementById("quantity");
    var quantity = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    if (quantity==3)
    {
       value="5.00";
    }
    else if (quantity==2)
    {
       value="2.00";
    }
    else
    {
       value="0.00";
    }
    document.getElementById("discount").value = value;
}
document.getElementById("quantity").onchange = updateDiscount;
```

Comment: Wow, this works... Thank you! I understand some of the elements, but it involved functions that I didn't know how to use, so I was only part way there. This will take me some time to interpret and understand, but I really appreciate your response, and would vote up your answer if I could.

Comment: You're welcome. If you accept the answer (by click the check mark on its left), it will signal to others that they can stop worrying about it.